# I swapped Pepe coin for eth on my trust wallet and can't find the eth in my wallet. Please help 

Tags: transactions

Hey guys can you please help me?

I swapped my Pepe coins for Eth on my trust wallet and can't find the eth yet.
Transaction hx:
0x613716e77ff08fc9e17084a7aa1a55e156ea65ff08c907e097e2680bfcbaeeb2

Answer (score 1):

That specific transaction was an approval transaction approving the 1inch aggregation router contract to spend your funds (required for a swap). This itself did not transfer any of your $PEPE coins.

However there was a following transaction from the same address [1] which was a transfer (not using 1inch) of 1,500,000 $PEPE to 0x15827fe5fb782e1ddcecc4c2b8ac002deac08cbd.

This is where your PEPE is.

[1] https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5a893b02bd008e1352babbd108cfef0dcd3a21fa495cd7b35e93d59470d565b3

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for taking the time to answer.